# Xubuntu 16.04 LTS Xfce themes look ugly after restart

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, themes, xfce, lts

When I delete the folder `~/.config/xfce4/` and login again, the theme looks okay as shown:

[image: Normal appearance]

But when I do another login, the window panes, panel, buttons etc. look ugly, and I am unable to change the theme by going to **Settings Manager** ➜ **Appearance** ➜ **Style** (I mean the style is using Greybird, as it should be, but it doesn't change when I click on different styles). I've also tried to use the `unity-tweak-tool`, but it didn't work.

Screenshot of the ugly appearance:

[image: Ugly appearance]

If I run `xfsettingsd` in terminal, it doesn't work as a workaround, but this message is shown:

```
WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-cHagy63RaP: Conexão recusada
```

The theme changes to the correct ones, but almost instantly the ugly theme takes place.

I've already reinstalled `xubuntu-desktop` and `xfce4` packages. Tried `xfce-theme-manager` also. When I remove the dir `~/.cache` and restart lightdm, it doesn't work either.

I forgot to tell that I have 3 monitors connected to 2 graphical cards:

```
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3] (rev a2)
```

My default graphical card selected in BIOS is the onboard (Intel).

When running `xfsettingsd` with debug mode:

```
$ export XFSETTINGSD_DEBUG=1
$ xfsettingsd --replace --no-daemon
xfce4-settings(xsettings): _XSETTINGS_S0 registered on screen 0
xfce4-settings(xsettings): 29 settings changed (serial=0, len=1164)
xfce4-settings(xsettings): resource manager (xft) changed (len=193)
xfce4-settings(displays): Detected CRTC 63.
xfce4-settings(displays): Detected CRTC 151.
xfce4-settings(displays): Detected CRTC 152.
xfce4-settings(displays): Detected CRTC 64.
xfce4-settings(displays): Detected CRTC 65.
floating point exception core dump
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please avoid posing image links for a forum that requires registration/login.  Save the images to your computer, and add them using the editor here so that they are displayed in your question.

Comment: @Dorian , I did what you've suggested, thanks.   The other screenshot:  [Screenshot ugly 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTxlc.png)

Comment: If change the window manager theme in Settings/Window Manager/style, it only changes the icons of the windows. The appearance of xubuntu remais the same as the screenshots.

Comment: I've uploaded the trace of the [crash of xsettings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zx6wk9rig4jmhkj/_usr_bin_xfsettingsd.1000.crash?dl=0).

Comment: I forgot to told that I have 3 monitors connected in 2 graphical cards:
`00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3] (rev a2)`

In software updates => additional drivers, I'm using  X.Org X server -- Nouvau display driver: http://i.imgur.com/plCz8NV.png.

Comment: Could this problem be generated by Xorg? When I delete the folder `~/.config/xfce4` and login again the theme is ok, but the two monitors connected to my geforce become disabled (I have one monitor connected to the onboard GPU and 2 to geforce). If I leave them like this, the theme doesn't change if I logout and login again, but if I configure them, in the next login the Xorg crashes right before the login and the theme becomes ugly like I described: [log of Xorg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3t751tpwqwq8cpa/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash?dl=0).

Comment: This is a strange problem...  Have you tried reinstalling Xorg?

Comment: @Dorian, I tryed `sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg`, but the package 'xserver-xorg' isn't installed. I also installed nvidia-current and nvidia-settings with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings` and got a "unable to connect to x server connection refused" and solved with [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586633&page=2&p=9916841#post9916841)

Comment: Related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/892391/why-cant-i-arrange-the-icons-on-my-xubuntu-16-04-desktop